# AspectJ declare parents on complex hierarchy

Tags: java, parent, aspectj, declare

There is a possibility in AspectJ to modify the class hierarchy using **declare** statements :

```
declare parents : TypePattern extends Type;
```

From http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/annotations-decp.html

Basically it allow you to "insert" a class in the hierarchy, here I insert X class :

```
 1. Child extends Parent                   -->   Child extends X extends Parent 
 2. Child extends SomeClass extends Parent -->   Child extends X extends SomeClass extends X extends Parent
```

However I am looking for a notation that will allow me to resolve the second case to :

```
 2. Child extends SomeClass extends Parent  -->   Child extends SomeClass extends X extends Parent
```

My problem is I have Child extends X and SomeClass extends X. Do you know AspectJ notation that would solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work?

```
declare parents : Child extends SomeClass;
declare parents : SomeClass extends X;
declare parents : X extends Parent;
```

I guess I am not exactly sure what your goal is.